# Writing my own version of kbhit using <ncurses.h> for linux

Tags: c++, ncurses

```
bool kbhit(void)
{
   // function without the 4 lines of code below will not work
   // but they also screw up the console
   initscr();             
   cbreak();
   noecho();
   nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);

    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
    int ch = getch();
    if (ch != ERR) {
        ungetch(ch);
        refresh();
        return true;
    } else {
        refresh();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Since ncurses do not have kbhit, I found the function above. But they screw up the console. This is what happens when I try to print the follow:
See picture[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to fix it? It is not supposed to be output like that?

Comment: You don't need ncurses to implement `kbhit()`. It's just `select()` on fd 0 with zero timeout. However mixing this with buffered input such as `cin` is unlikely to work well.

Comment: Oh forgot that you do need to put the terminal in raw non-canonical mode for this to work, see e.g. https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html

Comment: Sounds like he's using **`printf`**.  That won't work (because *curses* puts the screen in raw mode...), but the sample code is incomplete, allowing only guessing.

Answer (score 1):

That's called "staircasing".

The example of **`kbhit`** starts curses, but does not exit from curses (using **`endwin`**).  If your program tries using non-curses calls such as **`printf`**, the terminal will still be in raw mode — and that will persist after exiting to the shell (unless something resets the terminal).